# removing initial values from a list

Tags: python, list

Hi I have function that calculates moving averages given a list. Here is the code:

```
def calculate(self, alist, days=2):

    averages = []
    signals  = []
    prices   = [float(n) for n in alist[1::2]]
    window   = collections.deque(maxlen=days)

    for price in prices:
        window.append(price)
        averages.append(0.00)
        signals.append("")
        if len(window) == days:
            mavg = sum(window) / days
            averages[-1] = mavg
            if price < mavg:
                signals[-1] = "SELL"
            elif price > mavg:
                signals[-1] = "BUY"

    averages[:] = ("%.2f" % avg for avg in averages)

    return averages, signals
```

It gives the following output:

```
DATE            CLOSING        INDICATOR        SIGNAL
2013-10-01      887.00         0.00                                 
2013-10-02      887.99         0.00                                 
2013-10-03      876.09         0.00                                 
2013-10-04      872.35         0.00                                 
2013-10-07      865.74         877.83           SELL                
2013-10-08      853.67         871.17           SELL
```

Is there a way that I can remove the initial 0's from printing so that my output looks like:

```
DATE            CLOSING        INDICATOR        SIGNAL
2013-10-01      887.00                                         
2013-10-02      887.99                                          
2013-10-03      876.09                                          
2013-10-04      872.35                                          
2013-10-07      865.74         877.83           SELL                
2013-10-08      853.67         871.17           SELL
```

Comment: Where does it give this output? There's nothing in your code that prints anything in a columnar format like this.

Comment: @abarnert-the function is called in another module.

Comment: is there a way to check if there was a previous buy or sell then do nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def calculate(self, alist, days=2):

    # rest of your functions

    tol=0.01
    averages[:] = ("%.2f" % avg if abs(avg)>=tol else ' '  for avg in averages)

    return averages, signals
```

Comment: @drewk-is there a way to check if there was a previous buy or sell then do nothing?

Comment: I am sure there is, but it would appear that data lies outside this method. What is `alist` comprised of?

Comment: Is there a way to change the buy condition: if the closing price toady was higher than the moving average and if the closing price on previous day was lower than previous days moving average, then create a moving average?

Comment: You should give it a try and if you have issues -- ask another question. There is simply not enough to solve your issues with comments.